# SQLAlchemy fails to delete object with foreign key relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My `User` model has a relationship to the `EmailHistory` model. When I try to query and delete a user, I get the error `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`. I already specified `cascade='all, delete-orphan'` in the relationship. How do I delete the related rows when I delete the user?

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    emails = db.relationship('EmailHistory', cascade='all, delete-orphan', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

class EmailHistory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using MySQL or derivatives and could you post the actual tables with their constraints? What you've configured are the [ORM level cascades](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html), which kinda overlap with the DB side constraints. Read the linked docs for proper explanation on the subject.

Comment: From my shell `>>> User.query.filter(id>1).delete()`

Comment: think I have to add ondelete option..

Comment: `user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)`, solves my problem.

Comment: Got similar question and come across this SO thread, @AvinashRaj 's solution works well in my case, but it is weird that `cascade='all, delete'` in `relationship()` does not work as expected .